# How do i import a package that is on the same folder but not on the same location?

Tags: java, import, package

I've got a Folder named `Engine` which has 2 other Folders which are `Screen` and `Scene`

On the `Screen.java` file which is located on `Engine/Screen/Screen.java` I want to import the file `Engine/Scene/Scene.java`. I have tried with this packages and imports on each file

on the Screen.java:

```
package Engine; 
import Engine.Screen;
```

and on the Scene.java:

```
package Engine;
```

I could change the structure for it to work but I don't know how I would change it

Comment: "the same folder but not the same location", this is not possible. if your package statements are correct, the import statements shouldn't be a problem. package Engine.Scene; and package Engine.Screen; (keep in mind that normally packages start with lower letters)

Comment: ive got it wrong sorry

Comment: If the location of the files are correct on the other hand, the package should be `package Engine.Screen;` or `package Engine.Scene;` with the full qualified name `Engine.Screen.Screen` or `Engine.Scene.Scene`.

Comment: Also consider adopting the Java naming conventions. Packages are all lowercase, classes are in CamelCase.

Comment: so now i have everything in one folder and i have the packages like this on the Scene.java: `package engine.scene;` and on the Screen.java `package engine.screen;`

Comment: but when i compile Screen.java it says that `engine.scene` does not exist

Comment: @IcoderGameDev because the package statements aren't correct. If you moved it all into the engine folder, the package is just package engine; don't add the .scene or .screen unless that directory (package) is actually there and contains that class

Comment: i just had to remove all the package things  because they weren't needed now it works

Comment: actually, the 'package things' would work if you applied them correctly. removing them all together is the same as working in the default package, which is usually not recommended.